# Ruby access element from each_with_index

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

How I can print only the index returned from the last line call:

```
def collatz_sequence( seed )
    sequence = [ seed ]
    n = seed

    while 1 != n
        n = ( 0 == n % 2 ) ? n/2 : 3*n + 1
        sequence.push( n )
    end

    return sequence
end

limit = 1_000_000
puts ( 1..limit ).map { | i | collatz_sequence( i ).length }.each_with_index.max
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "this call" mean? There are 12 different call sites in your code.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The last line call, I'm trying to return only the index. Right now is returning the index and the element.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it returns an Array containing the element and an index, the index being last.

```
puts ( 1..limit ).map {| i | collatz_sequence( i ).length}.each_with_index.max.last
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot